# python 3.5 converting a list of bytes into ascii

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, ascii

I have a list of words that is in bytes but I want to switch them into ascii.

What I'm trying to get:

```
print(delimitednames)
['the\x00  ', 'tree\x00  ', 'grew\x00  ', 'tall\x00  ']
```

What I'm getting currently

```
print(delimitednames)
[b'the\x00  ', b'tree\x00  ', b'grew\x00  ', b'tall\x00  ']
```

If I try:

```
delimitednames = [x.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for x in delimitednames]
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I'm not too familiar with bytes so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any links or advice? Thank you.

edit: updating answer

result obtained using line

```
delimitednames = [str(x,'ascii', 'ignore') for x in delimitednames]
```

Comment: what is your intended output? Could you update your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the str function instead in Python 3.x:

```
delimitednames = [str(x,'ascii', 'ignore') for x in delimitednames]
```

Assuming you don't need the nullbytes and whitespaces, you can add .strip('\x00 ') to the string